# How To Detect When The Minus Button in a UITableViewCell Was Tapped During Editing?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with editing enabled. I'd like to hide specific elements of a cell when the minus button is tapped, but can't find a way to detect that the minus button was tapped. Anyone know how to detect this?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to subclass UITableViewCell, and implement the method willTransitionToState